# check the audio stream

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Need your help, I check whether the audio stream when you press a button or when the program starts at the moment when you press a button and the audio stream is not available then that does not occur, the music does not play and no any response from the program no I want you to realize how such a response as possible to do it?

startup code media player:

```
public void playMain() {
releaseMP();
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "start Stream");
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try {
    if(pdaStream.isChecked()){
        Main_stream = "http://145.255.233.204:58000/radio_pda";             
    }else{
        Main_stream = "http://145.255.233.204:58000/radio";
    }
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Main_stream);
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "prepareAsync");
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();;
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();  
    }  
    });  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What best you can do just start progress dialog before object creation of MediaPlayer and dismiss this after mMediaPlayer.start().

Try this and let me know.

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        //start you progress dialog here
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
        mMediaPlayer
        .setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(
        getApplicationContext(),
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        // dismiss your dialog here

        }
    }
        };
        task.execute();
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, but did not help in onPostExecute did .setVisibility (View.GONE); 
when you press the play ProgressBar appears and disappears immediately without waiting for the music playback

Comment: Thanks I realized my mistake, I did not see a progress bar in the place